# Article of R. Dr. Twersky on Mishne Torah

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam, internet, mishneh-torah

Is R. Dr. Yitzchak Twersky's article: "Some Non-Halakhic Aspects of the Mishneh Torah," published in: Jewish Medieval and Renaissance Studies, ed. A. Altmann (Cambridge, 1967), pp. 95-118, available for free online?

Comment: It looks like lots of college libraries have it.  http://www.worldcat.org/title/jewish-medieval-and-renaissance-studies/oclc/463286190?referer=di&ht=edition

Comment: my college library says it as the printed version and an online version. when i click online version it just brings me to worldcat...the struggle for knowledge is real

Comment: @Veritas I didn't find it online, sorry. As the comments indicate many college libraries have it, sorry. For future reference, answers generally shouldn't be used for comments. When you get 50 rep you will be able to comment on others' posts.

Comment: If you’d like I can post a particular page(s) of his essay as an answer or somehow scan the whole essay and post (send) as a PDF. (Yes, I own the book.)